# How may i prevent search engines from crawling a subdomain on my website?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain, cpanel, robots.txt

I have cPanel installed on my website.

1. I went to the Domains section on cPanel
2. I clicked on subdomains.
3. I assigned the subdomain name (e.g : personal.mywebsite.com )
4. It wanted me to assign document root folder also. I assigned mywebsite.com/personal

   if i create robots.txt in my website root(e.g : website.com)

   User-agent:

   Disallow: /personal/

Can it also block personal.mywebsite.com?

what should i do?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to block URLs on `personal.example.com`, visit `http://personal.example.com/robots.txt` (resp. `https` instead of `http`).

It doesn’t matter how your server organizes folders in the backend, it only matters which robots.txt is available when accessing this URL.