# Disable crawling for subdomain

Tags: seo, subdomain, robots.txt

I want to disable crawling for my subdomains.

For example: 
my main domain is maindomain.com
subdomain_one.com (add-on domain)
subdomain_two.com (add-on domain)

So I want to disable crawling for subdomain_one.maildomain.com.

I have used this in robot.txt:

```
   User-agent: *
   Disallow: /subdomain_one/
   Disallow: /subdomain_two/
```

Comment: 1) What do you mean with "disable SEO"? Disallow crawling and/or indexing? 2) You listed 4 different domains in your question, and only one of these domains has a subdomain. Could you please check and [edit] your question accordingly?

Comment: thank you for your response ya i mean to say that not to index  for subdomian , so i have used robot.txt is that correct way to do please reply me

Comment: I see. I removed the `.htaccess` side question as it’s not related to your main question about robots.txt. Feel free to create a new question here for that.

Answer (score 6):

The file must be called `robots.txt`, not `robot.txt`.

If you want to disallow all bots to crawl your subdomain, you have to place a robots.txt file in the document root **of this subdomain**, with the following content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Each host needs its own `robots.txt`. You can’t specify subdomains inside of the robots.txt, only [beginnings of URL paths](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/50711/17633).

So if you want to block all files on `http://sub.example.com/`, the robots.txt must be accessible from `http://sub.example.com/robots.txt`.

It [doesn’t matter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24581854/1591669) how your sites are organized on the server-side, it only matters what is publicly accessible.

Comment: Note that some search engines (e.g., Google) may still *index* your URLs. But if you disable crawling in robots.txt, Google won’t use your content for their search result snippet.